# Repetitive JavaScript (jQuery) code

Tags: javascript, jquery, non-repetitive

Here's something simple I am doing. I have some div's, each called ".item-1", ".item-2", etc. When the user hovers on ".item-1", the "#city-info-1" div slides up, while it slides down when the user hovers off. I knew enough to do that, and know enough that the way I've coded it isn't the best way possible. Just curious how others would do this, so I don't have to repeat practically the same code every time. Appreciate any suggestions :)

```
    $('#city-info-1, #city-info-2, #city-info-3, #city-info-4, #city-info-5, #city-info-6, #city-info-7').hide();

    $('.item-1').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-1').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-1').hide();
    });

    $('.item-2').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-2').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-2').hide();
    });

    $('.item-3').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-3').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-3').hide();
    });

    $('.item-4').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-4').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-4').hide();
    });

    $('.item-5').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-5').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-5').hide();
    });

    $('.item-6').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-6').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-6').hide();
    });

    $('.item-7').hover(function() {
        $('#city-info-7').stop().slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
        $('#city-info-7').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Please post the HTML you've written.

Answer (score 2):

based on you current markup you can use [`start with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
$('div[id^=city-info]').hide();

$('div[class^=item]').hover(function() {
      var cls = $(this).attr('class').replace('item', "")
      $('#city-info' + cls).stop().slideToggle(400);
  }, function() {
      $('#city-info' + cls).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an unique ID(only some prefix and the integer number, i.e. 'i-666') for each if the item and set same class for all.

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
  var item_id = item.attr('id');
  $('#city-info-' + item_id).stop().slideToggle(400);
}, function() {
  $('#city-info-' + item_id).hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, just [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) if you want a valid page, then css identifiers cannot start with a number.

Comment: Yes, im aware of that, it was just a simplest example. Any good developer wouldn't create lots of number IDs :]

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic css class and attach behavior to it rather than specific elements.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/K3mbE/1/

**Javascript**:

```
$('.slider').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('div').stop().slideToggle(400);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('div').hide();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="slider">Seattle
    <div>It rains a lot</div>
</div>
<div class="slider">New York
    <div>Greatest city on earth</div>
</div>
<div class="slider">Trantor
    <div>Greatest city in the galexy</div>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Each ".item-" is different and the content inside each "#city-info-" is different...

Comment: Right, the html has the different content while the class name & it's behavior are shared.  Added a working example.

Answer (score 0):

a div can have multiple class so you can have each of thoses divs have a common class name

```
<div class="item item-1"></div>
<div class="item item-2"></div>
<div class="item item-3"></div>
...
```

so you can select :

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
        ...
    }, function() {
       ....
    });
```

please show us your html, because this looks like something you can simply do with css